# Почему не изменяется код?

Tags: кэширование, yii

Использую Yii.
Залила новую версию на сервер, где исправила баги, и что я вижу? На сервере новый файл, а через браузер захожу, открывается старый вариант.
Все пути и файлы перепроверила, кэш чистила, на разных компьютерых и браузерах заходила. Одна и та же картина.

Comment: исправления были в php или в стилях и скриптах?

Comment: @IVsevolod в php

Comment: @ЖуЖу отсюда поподробней. Как должен был изменится код? И какой код? HTML? И как должен был измениться?

Comment: @IVsevolod  <zanuda>На php тоже скрипты пишутся :)</zanuda>

Answer (score 2):

assets поробуйте почистить                      http://yiiframework.ru/doc/cookbook/ru/core.assets

Comment: не спасло...

Answer (score 2):

Вообще можно вообще вычистить весь КЭШ. Это же просто

```
Yii::app()->cache->clear();
```

Comment: вариант хороший, но не спас.

Comment: ребутни сервак.